# What is the Time Complexity of this code sample? like nested loop, but inner loop is a fixed number

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

```
result = []
for i in n:
  for jj in range(len(m)):
    if jj < 3:
      result.append((n,m))
    else:
      jj = len(m)
```

- m, n are two python array
- inner loop is maximum 3

## Thinking

- O(n)? because inner looping is in a fixed amount
- O(n*m)?
- O(n*3)? this is not the correct way :(

---

> What is the correct O time complexity for this?

Comment: Where do you see that the inner loop can execute only 3 times?

Comment: You need to trace your code, research the complexity of each operation (append and len), and finish your own derivation.  *Then* you're in a position to post this question.

Comment: If the inner loop is actually fixed, then the *entire* inner loop can be written as a step. Being the *only* step, it must be the *significant step*, and in that case your time complexity would just be O(n). I'm just taking your word that the inner loop is fixed though, if it is not this logic does not apply.

Comment: thanks, find the problem, code sample is not that good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time complexity of the statement inside the inner loop is in `O(1)`. Because, it is just only one comparison and one variable assignment, and computing the `len(m)` is done in `O(1)`. The remaining is straightforward: two nested loop with `n` and `m` iterations. Therefore, the time complexity is `O(m * n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `O(n^2 + n * m)`. The inner loop is executed at most three times, and in each of those iterations, you are doing this operation: `result.append((n,m))`. The time complexity of this is `O(n+m)`, since you are appending two lists of sizes `n` and `m`, respectively, to the list `result`. So that means you are doing `O(n+m)` operations three times in each iteration, meaning the total number of operations is `O(3 * n * (n + m)) = O(n^2 + n * m)`.

Edit: I used `n` and `m` for lists and their sizes interchangeably, but I guess that is understandable.